# Same package in two Azure Artefacts feeds consume twice the space of the package?

Tags: azure-devops

We might need to upload the very same (binary wise, file date might differ though) files/folder as an universal package to two different Azure Artefacts feeds.

Now I am wondering if the size for the same blob being available in two feeds is counted once or twice when computing the Azure Artefacts space consumption costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We might need to upload the very same (binary wise, file date might differ though) files/folder as an universal package to two different Azure Artefacts feeds.

In this case, this package will consume artifact space twice.

In Azure Devops, the storage space consumed by different feeds/projects is calculated separately.

You could check it in **Organization Settings/Project Settings  -> Storage**.

So even if you publish the exact same files as a package to two feeds, it will still consume storage space twice.